# Javascript won't work with php in joomla

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla

here is my problem. I'm now trying to get all the result from the joomla database and shown as a check box. Then if my php code get no result from the database it should prompt out the error message and hide the particular DIV in the joomla. But my code is not working, it wont hide the DIV element i wanted to.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php

$q = $_GET['q'];


define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');


$db = JFactory::getDBO();


$sql="SELECT courseid FROM course WHERE campusid = '$q'";


// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($sql);// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if($results){
     foreach($results as $result)
     {
        echo "<label class='option block'>";
         echo "<input type='checkbox' id ='courseID' name='courseID' value='$result->courseid' onChange='showBox2(this.value)'><span class='checkbox'></span>";
 echo $result->courseid;
 echo '</label>';
 echo '<br/>';

 } 

}
else{ echo 'Error. No data found in '.$q;
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function myFunction(){  document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display =none; };';
echo '</script>';}
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

DiV element i wanted to hide:

```
 <div id="hideBox2" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="spacer-t40 spacer-b30">
                        <div class="tagline"><span> Date Open For Registration & Course Start Date </span></div><!-- .tagline -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="frm-row">
                        <div class="section colm colm6">
                            <label class="field prepend-icon">
                                <input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="gui-input">
                                <label class="link-icon jsn-icon-calendar"></i></label>  
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end section -->

                        <div class="section colm colm6">
                            <label class="field prepend-icon">
                                <input type="text" id="to" name="to" class="gui-input">
                                <label class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></label>  
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end section -->
                    </div><!-- end .frm-row section -->

                </div>
```

In addition, this is a php file.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the quote characters in your javascript part:

```
echo 'function myFunction(){  document.getElementById(\'hideBox2\').style.display = \'none\'; };';
```

Or, probably even better, output the javascript directly:

```
?> function myFunction(){  document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display = 'none'; }; <?php
```

Don't forget to put your "none" value into quotes too.

However your code looks messy. I can't find where you output the div you wanna hide. You output the list before the body is even opened. Also, you can check the database result count prior the output and "decide" if you need the holding div after all.

Comment: else{ echo 'Error. No data found in '.$q;
echo 'function myFunction(){  document.getElementById(\'hideBox2\').style.display = \'none\'; };';}
?>


Is this okay? but it still wont work :(

Comment: the output turn to be like this 

Error. No data found in Segi2221321312function myFunction(){ document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display = 'none'; };

It treat it as an echo message =.=

Comment: I had update the html code above, that is the DIV element that i wanted to hide if i get no result from the database

Comment: Wait a minute...is myFunction ever called? Try replacing that line with (maybe you try to hide it before it gets rendered or don't call your function at all): document.onload = function () { document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display = 'none'; };

Comment: something like this?

echo '<script type="text/Javascript">document.onload = function () { document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display = 'none'; };</script>';

Comment: this might work. Sadly it's very difficult to locate the problem when all the algorithm and code is presented this way.

Comment: do u have any skype or chat link? :) I think we can discuss there

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to charge you for that :) I suggest you clarify your problem first and hopefully someone will answer it right.

Comment: echo '<script type="text/Javascript">document.onload = function () { document.getElementById('hideBox2').style.display = 'none'; };</script>'; 

This code is not working :(

Comment: you forgot the escaoing once again. Try switching to doublequotes if that makes it easier: echo '<script type="text/Javascript">document.onload = function () { document.getElementById("hideBox2").style.display = "none"; };</script>'; Also try using firebug and see what error you get. Try putting an alert inside the function etc. Do some debugging

Comment: I had try to put double quotes on it and also i also trying to debug it with alert...the php code still not running the javascript=.=